# Using a Java REST service to process incoming repeatable XmlInlineBinaryData elements

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

I am currently using JAXB generated classes to reflect a schema for a REST request I receive which may contain Base 64 encoded binary data elements.

The payload I receive is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ProcessRequest> <DeliveryDate>2015-12-13</DeliveryDate>  <AttachmentBinary>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFoA</AttachmentBinary> <AttachmentBinary>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFoA</AttachmentBinary> </ProcessRequest>
```

I am implementing my solution using the Jersey REST API and only originally assumed a single  element.

Am I right in understanding JAXB allows me to accept repeating elements using XmlElementWrapper ?

My biggest challenge is also streaming this  to disk since it contains large image files and I don't wish to hold it in memory. 
Is there an efficient way of setting up an input stream and writing each element to a separate file ? I may need to write it to disk first, access a few bytes to determine its filetype then rename it  (or find a way to do this on the fly)

Thanks in advance